# BrowserRouter not opening with url param

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have the following Router configuration:

```
const App = () => (
  <HashRouter>
    <div className="app">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route exact path="/search" component={Search} />
        <Route path="/details/:id" component={Details} />
        <Route component={FourOhFour} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </HashRouter>
)
```

When I load `http://localhost:8080/#/details/12345` my Component Details is rendered correctly;
if i switch to BrowserRouter, load `http://localhost:8080/details/12345`, I get a blank page: index.html is rendered correctly, but i get the following errors in the console:

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:8080/details/public/style.css' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
>   checking is enabled.
>
> GET http://localhost:8080/details/public/bundle.js 404 (Not Found) 1:1
>
> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost:8080/details/public/bundle.js' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled.

I am following an online course, i am using webpack, i think i have all the configuration equal to the one on the course, the app in the course videos works correctly

My webpack.config.js is as follows:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './js/ClientApp.jsx'
  ],
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'cheap-eval-source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'public/'
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    publicPath: '/public/',
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true,
    chunks: true
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // {
      //   enforce: 'pre',
      //   test: /\.jsx?$/,
      //   loader: 'eslint-loader',
      //   exclude: /node_modules/
      // },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not serving the bundle and styles from the correct path. Which is why it's not loading.

Comment: in your `webpack.config.js`, have you set the `contentBase` property inside `devServer` ?

Comment: @Dane i tried setting it up, but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you show your webpack config. Also check this issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3027